# Binding to KeyBinding Gesture

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set up an input gesture as follows:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand}" Gesture="{x:Static local:Resources.MyCommandGesture}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Here Resources is a resource .resx file and MyCommandGesture is a string defined in it.  This produces the following exception:

Unable to cast object of type System.String to type System.Windows.Input.InputGesture.

There is no problem if I just replace the binding with the string from the resource file (such as Gesture="F2").  Any suggestions?

Edit:
We can achieve the desired result in code behind by doing something like the following:

```
KeyGestureConverter kgc = new KeyGestureConverter();
KeyGesture keyGestureForMyCommand = (KeyGesture)kgc.ConvertFromString(Resources.MyCommandGesture);
this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(VM.MyCommand, keyGestureForMyCommand));
```

I was hoping to find a XAML solution.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because you're expected to place a valid value from the System.Windows.Input.Key enumeration into the Gesture property of your KeyBinding.

If you do this:

```
Gesture="F2"
```

... even though it *feels* like you're putting in a string, you're actually putting in a valid named constant from the enumeration, hence it works.

However, if you use this:

```
Gesture="{x:Static local:Resources.MyCommandGesture}"
```

It bypasses the enum mapping because you're using the x:Static markup extension and ultimately are saying "this is a string".  Even if the value is equal to a valid constant name from the "Key" enum, it won't work.

If you really can't live with putting the key name in XAML, I personally wouldn't use the resources file.  Rather, I'd have a class which defines them as the correct type i.e. KeyGestures:

```
public class KeyGestures
{
    public static KeyGesture KeyCommandAction1 { get { return new KeyGesture(Key.F1); } }
    public static KeyGesture KeyCommandAction2 { get { return new KeyGesture(Key.F2); } }
}
```

And use in XAML accordingly:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand1}" Gesture="{x:Static local:KeyGestures.KeyCommandAction1}" />
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand2}" Gesture="{x:Static local:KeyGestures.KeyCommandAction2}" />
```

Comment: The definition of the keyboard shortcuts in resource files is done as part of the localization support.  I understand the why the error is occurring, what I'm hoping to find is a way to convert from a string to InputGesture in xaml.

Comment: You could use an IValueConverter class (overly verbose imo), or alternatively use the same approach I described but convert your localised resource file item into a KeyGesture using Enum.Parse so you get the benefit of localisation but add code to convert the result to a valid KeyGesture.  I can't see how you'd achieved it purely in XAML.

Comment: Can you use IValueConverter on the Gesture property?  It is not a dependency property.