# How to create customizable WPF shortcuts

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine

I'm creating shortcuts for a user. I want the key and the modifiers to be customizable by the user. I tried to use a x:Static variable like in the example bellow from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30579416/5712419

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="{x:Static local:ShortcutKeysModifiers.SaveKey}" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SaveUnderCommand}" Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Key="S" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Here is how I created my static key

```
public class ShortcutKeysModifiers
{
    public static Key SaveKey = Key.S;
}
```

My error is this
[image: Static members not supported. Cant use Static variable as a key and can't set 'null' on property of type 'Key']

How can I modify the Key and the Modifiers from the code-behind for a KeyBinding ? Do I need to use something else than a KeyBinding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CommandBinding for that:

In xaml file:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:UserControl.MyCommand}" Executed="SaveCommandExecuted"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

In class UserControl (or other adapt with xaml):

```
    public static RoutedCommand MyCommand = new RoutedCommand();
```

in code Behind:

```
    private void SaveCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         //Do something when shorcut called
    }
```

in the constructor of the class:

```
MyCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control));
```